# Is there a way to import or load libraries in service worker?

Tags: fetch, service-worker

I am writing a service worker for my app which, in 'activate' state reads and writes to IndexedDB. For reading or writing in IndexedDB, I use a library called 'idb'(https://unpkg.com/idb?module). Is there ant possible way to import libraries in service workers. Also, the library use ES6 imports and exports, will that be a problem?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience.....I researched and figured out the solution

Comment: And how does your solution look like?

Comment: I've already answered it. Please read the answer written below. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To import scripts/libraries in service workers I had to use `importScripts()` rather than `fetch()` and that did the trick. Also, the imported library gets added to the ServiceWorkerGlobalScope, meaning I had to use `this.<library-name>` to access the library.
Also, the ServiceWorkerGlobalScope doesn't have support for ES6 import/export, that's why I needed to build the package with `npm build` and then use it.

```
importScripts('index-min.js');
this.idb();
```